# Chrome is limiting my chrome extension background file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I made a Chrome extension that tracks user web time and classifies it. Nothing new, I saw at least 15 extensions that do the same.

The thing is, that some computers are not tracking the user activity and show nothing. While in some like mine, it works perfectly fine.

All that tracking logic is placed in the background file. while the rest of logic in the popup works fine.

I saw that a friend's computer gives the warning:

"This extension is not trusted by Enhanced Safe Browsing"
And the other extensions that do the same work fine on their computers. Is there something else I should add or modify in the developer dashboard?

In privacy data usage I checked the "Web History" and explained in detail what the extension does. Is all saved locally and don't recollect any information outside the extension.

I made it using svelte with "sveltekit-adapter-chrome-extension" adapter.

My extension link: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/firu-webtime-tracker/jhadlflplfkmelbpaoopgogcomhoeblj

I put some console logs and discover that is executing the background file, but for some reason is not saving the items in some computers.